# Errors in php script apparently all coming from one line of code

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with a PHP script which apparently is getting errors from one single line. The top line in this bit of code is apparently causing quite a bit of trouble:

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "./upload/".$imageName)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT " .$pages. " SET inmenu='$inmenu', pagid='$pagid', title='$titlename', content='$contentname', image='$image', youtube='$youtube'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

    header("Location: index.php"); 
 }
```

The errors I'm getting for the top line of code:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: ' in cms/new.php on line 131

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at cms/new.php:131) in cms/new.php on line 85
```

First I thought CHmodding the upload folder to 777 would solve this error, but apparently it doesn't. I really don't know what to do anymore. Is there anyone who can help?

The complete block of code that includes the little snippet above:

```
<?php 
     }
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("location:login.php");
    }

 include("config.php");

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 

 //set root
 $root = getcwd ();

 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $inmenu = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['inmenu']));
 $pagid = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pagid']))));
 $titlename = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']));
 $contentname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['contentedit']));
 $youtube = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['youtube'])); 

 // check to make sure both fields are entered
 if ($titlename == '' || $pagid == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, display the form again
 renderForm($pagid, $titlename, $contentname, $error);
 }
 else
 {

    if(file_exists($root."/upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]))
    {
        $filename = explode(".",$_FILES['image']['name']);
        $randomnumber = rand(0, 10000);
        $imageName = $filename[0].$randomnumber.".".$filename[1];
    }
    else
    {
        $imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    }

    $image = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars("/upload/".$imageName));

 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "./upload/".$imageName)) {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT " .$pages. " SET inmenu='$inmenu', pagid='$pagid', title='$titlename', content='$contentname', image='$image', youtube='$youtube'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: index.php"); 
 }
 else {
     // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT " .$pages. " SET inmenu='$inmenu', pagid='$pagid', title='$titlename', content='$contentname', youtube='$youtube'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: index.php"); 
 }
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
 {
 renderForm('','','');
 }
?>
```

Comment: It may not be the first line that's causing the problem, but the missing `INTO` for your [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) which is most likely the cause. Try `"INSERT INTO " .$pages.`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is also not the problem.

Comment: You're welcome. However, we'd need to see more code. Plus, your `headers already sent` error, that could be a number of things. Two-three lines of code, just isn't enough.

Comment: sure about the line count

Comment: I'm sure about the line count. I included the complete block of code in my question.

Comment: threr are not 131 lines in that code

Comment: One of the things that could be playing a role in this, is your use of the period for `./upload/` in `if (move_uploaded_file` and not using it above that line. There could be a path issue. The `headers already sent` means that output happening before your `session_start();` you could probably get away with this, by using `ob_start();` on top of `session_start();`

Comment: There's obviously 59 more lines above the OP's code ;-) @Dagon

Comment: i guess "complete" has some other meaning to the one i know

Comment: I doubt the `include("config.php");` contains 59 lines of code, but... I could be wrong. They don't build "complete" like they used to ;-) @Dagon

Comment: The other lines are HTML which is irrelevant for the question ;).

Comment: True and false. When you post an error message containing the line number of the (probable) error, and it's not in your code without telling anyone the whereabouts of line 131, then don't bother putting it in. It throws everybody off. @FrankKluyt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using double quotes you can just insert PHP variables so
Try this:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "./upload/".$imageName)) {

    $query = "INSERT " . $pages . SET inmenu=$inmenu, pagid=$pagid, title=$titlename, contenct=$contentname, image=$image, youtube=$youtube";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

    header("Location: index.php"); 
 }
```

Another way (if you'd like) would be this:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "./upload/".$imageName)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT " .$pages. " SET inmenu='".$inmenu."', pagid='".$pagid."',     title='".$titlename."', content='".$contentname."', image='".$image."', youtube='".$youtube."'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

    header("Location: index.php"); 
}
```

Comment: You're welcome Frank. Graag gedaan. Please also check the box for the correct answer. I need the points :P